# Default sqrt index to scriptstyle instead of scriptscriptstyle

Tags: superscripts, size, sqrt

In my document, I am using a font and size which just makes scriptscriptstyle too small, and it looks weird to me:

[image: With scriptscriptstyle index]

If instead of `\sqrt[3]{...}` I write `\sqrt[\scriptstyle 3]{...}` it looks better:

[image: With scriptstyle]

And I want to apply this to all the square roots in my document, without typing `\scriptstyle` every single time.

My first solution was this:

```
\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][\phantom{1}]{\oldsqrt[\scriptstyle#1]{#2}}
```

but then I can't use `\uproot{}` in `\sqrt` to adjust some fractions. (I'm not sure why, but it throws an error)

So, my next solution attempt was to look into the definition of `\sqrt` (using `\show` in a console)

```
> \sqrt =\long macro:
->\@ifnextchar [\@sqrt \sqrtsign .
<argument> \sqrt
```

then I looked into the `\@sqrt` definition:

```
> \@sqrt=macro:
[#1]->\root #1\of .
<argument> \@sqrt
```

finally I had a look at the `\root` definition and I found what I wanted:

```
> \root=macro:
#1\of ->\setbox \rootbox \hbox {$\m@th \scriptscriptstyle {#1}$}\mathpalette \r
@@t .
<argument> \root
```

so I just had to redefine `\root` to the exact same but changing `\scriptscriptstyle` to `\scriptstyle`. I tried the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\root}[1]{\setbox\rootbox\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle{#1}$}\mathpalette\r@@t}
\makeatother
```

but it just throws a ton of illegible errors and breaks the whole document. I don't think I understood correctly the definition of `\root`, so my code isn't okay. How would you do this?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not recommend hacking these macros but I think you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\root#1\of{\setbox\rootbox\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle{#1}$}\mathpalette\r@@t}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[3]{4}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is because from the definition you post

```
> \root=macro:
#1\of ->\setbox \rootbox \hbox {$\m@th \scriptscriptstyle {#1}$}\mathpalette \r
@@t .
<argument> \root
```

an `\of` is part of the `\root` definition.

Comment: Thank you! The `->` was confusing me.